# Why is chrome rendering this CSS in such a way

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I was trying to create a circle with i icon in it for with CSS. However, when page is first rendered the circle looks like an inverted egg and covers the border around it slightly. (Zoom in the browser to see issue in more details)

**The tricky part is, if you open Dev Tools and change any value related to it's position(width, height, whatever), everything will snap back to normal and it will become a circle.**

https://jsfiddle.net/2yjashje/

```
<div class="round-egg">
    i
</div>


.round-egg {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: white;
    color: #8DC641;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: help;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    border: 4px solid #8DC641;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**What is going on here?**

Comment: Border-radius:50%; and remove the border-bottom line

Comment: I'm guessing the `!important` is messing things up, as usual.

Comment: I can't quite understand your question, but is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/2yjashje/3/  - edited the link; I posted it as an answer below since I think it solves the issue (I'm using Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the letter "i" in its own span and increased the margin from top to vertically centre it. As for the circle, I modified the border-radius property, and then removed the border-bottom: none; property as well. Assuming you want a circle, you need the bottom border.

https://jsfiddle.net/2yjashje/3/

```
<div class="round-egg">
    <span class="icon">i</span>
</div>

.round-egg {
    font-size: 14px;
    background: white;
    color: #8DC641;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: help;
    border: 4px solid #8DC641;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}
.icon {
   display: block;
   margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would probably be useful.

Comment: Instead of the margin-top: 2px, you can use line-height...though chrome seems to need it to be set to 18px to get the right vertical alignment (line-height: 18px;)